# MySQL server impossible to delete

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am working on a ubuntu server, and I installed mysql-server-8.0, and i can't remove it now !
I tried to remove packages after a grep:

> sudo dpkg -P mysql-server-core-8.0 mysql-server-8.0 mysql-common mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-client-8.0

Then I got :

> dpkg: error processing package mysql-client-core-8.0 (--purge):
> dependency problems - not removing
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> mysql-server-8.0
> mysql-common
> mysql-client-8.0
> mysql-server-core-8.0
> mysql-client-core-8.0

When I'm trying to connect to mysql :

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I tried this too :

> sudo apt-get purge mysql*
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> sudo apt-get autoclean

But it looks like there is no solutions ..
Some errors coming back a lot of times :

> Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
> invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
> installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> mysql-server-8.0

Do you have an idea how to remove all things concerning mysql(-server)/ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to stop the problem with mysql-server-8.0

I just go in this path :

> /var/lib/dpkg/info$

and delete all files with mySQL

sudo rm mysql-client-8.0.md5sums mysql-client-core-8.0.md5sums mysql-common.conffiles .....

I can now unistall and re install !
Good luck :)